# How to build notepad++ from source using mingw

Tags: notepad++, mingw-w64

I tried to compile ++ from the sources, everything was compiled, until the moment when it was necessary to include the header files atl, such as atlbase.h and others. It turned out that there are no such header files in the delivery of the Mingw !!! Although the file in the readme in the folder of the gcc mentioned that it was compiled with the Mingw.